# Can ubuntu run on 512MB Ram?

Tags: system-requirements

I have a system which has 512 MB RAM. It is a 32Bit system
I like to work in ubuntu OS: does anyone have experience with installing/running Ubuntu on 512MB RAM? Will it run properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu itself will run , but not the unity desktop environment.

you may want to consider [the minimal iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) or maybe [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/help/) or [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) as they are designed to run with lower system specs.

Comment: but i want to install ubuntu 12.04 then? is it possible?

Comment: Yes , its possible ubuntu and its associated projects all follow the same version numbering system and minimal isos are available for all releases

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can!
[Ubuntu Sys Req](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) can help you out with everything you need.

However Xubuntu would be a better choice if you're looking for a lightweight GUI option.

Comment: but i want to install ubuntu 12.04 then? is it possible?

Comment: The system requirements at this page are deprecated. Should be updated quickly. IMO it is impossible to run full unity desktop on 512 MB of RAM only. Also this page refers to UNE that is not exist nowadays. I recommend [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/) as a start.

Comment: it'll be quite slow with the Unity Desktop, you can always choose the Ubuntu 2D option at bootup. But, it'd be better to install Xubuntu or as NikTh mentioned, Lubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 13.04 will definitely run as it has lower memory footprint and better speed than previous versions, for me it was around 230 MB at idle desktop. Ubuntu 12.04 won't be a good choice for your specs. If you want Long Term Support versions then better choose other versions such as Linux mint cinnamon , Lubuntu etc.

Good luck!!

Comment: did you run smoothly on 230 MB ram?